# How to change my email account sender "From" in outlook on vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have 2 email box account in my outlook so How can I change email account when I'm sending Email

**`"From"`**

[image]

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YL9F.jpg)

I need to send from my email address "anas3643@hotmail.com"

```
Sub Test_for_using()
'MVP OShon from VBATools.pl
    Dim oMail  As MailItem
    On Error GoTo blad
    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer":  Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(2)
    Case "Inspector": Set oMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
    Call odpowiedz_do_nadawcy(oMail)
    blad:
End Sub

Sub odpowiedz_do_nadawcy(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oReply As MailItem
    With Item
        Set oReply = .Forward
        Dim MyValue As Integer
        Dim x As String
        Dim emailNames(19) As String
        emailNames(1) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(2) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(3) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(4) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(5) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(6) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(7) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(8) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(9) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(10) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(11) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(12) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(13) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(14) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(15) = "anas.alwasel11@gmail.com"
        emailNames(16) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"
        emailNames(19) = "anas3643@hotmail.com"

        MyValue = CInt(Int((19 * rnd()) + 1))     ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
        x = emailNames(MyValue)
        oReply.Forward
        oReply.Recipients.Add (x)
        oReply.Send
        Set oReply = Item

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Have you tried Google?

Comment: Have you tried [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-sendusingaccount-property-outlook) ?

Answer (score 1):

> ## *MailItem.SendUsingAccount* Property
>
> Returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under
>   which the `MailItem` is to be sent. *(Read/write.)*
>
> ### **Syntax**:
>
> ***`expression`* `.` `SendUsingAccount`**
>
> - *expression* : An expression that returns a `MailItem` object.
>
> ### **Remarks**:
>
> The `SendUsingAccount` property can be used to specify the account
>   that should be used to send the `MailItem` when the `Send` method is
>   called. This property returns `Null` if the account specified for the
>   `MailItem` no longer exists.

- **More information at the [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-sendusingaccount-property-outlook).**

Comment: can you give some example please my email anas3643@hotmail.com

Comment: ***!Stack Overflow مرحبا لانس-آل-واسيل! مرحبا بكم في*** It's always good to see someone showing interest in learning the basics of coding,but Stack Overflow isn't really a **"free code writing service", it's more of a place where developers (of any experience level) can bring a ***specific question*** about a *specific issue*, share their **existing code** and explain (as best as possible) what's wrong, and what's been tried so far including examples of what they are trying to do.

Comment: ... ***All answers are kept on the website***, making it useful to others in the future.  If you search the site, I'm sure you will find examples of other doing whatever it is you're trying to do. Be sure to check out the **[tour]** as well as handy tips at "**[ask]**" and also "**[mcve]**".  Have you checked for similar questions Stack Overflow?  If you need a crash course in VBA, there are some excellent tutorials and other resources online, just a search away.  Feel free to **[edit]** your question if you'd like to add any more information.  ***Good Luck!***